# I can't sort out missing C++ library function dependencies

Tags: c++

I seem to somehow have an impossible situation, that I can only assume means my analysis is somehow wrong, since the following all seem to be true:

- The executable runs, so it must have all dependent functions provided
- The executable depends on a function I'll call Foo::Bar::_ex
- This function is not defined in any .a or .so file in the entire filesystem
- One of the dependent libraries requires this undefined function
- I cannot link the code into an executable because I can't find any library that provides this function

I can see the requirement of this function by the application by running ldd on the app, and seeing that it requires a library I'll call libExample.so. I can see by running objdump -T on the .so file that it requires the mystery function:

```
ldd APP
    libExample.so => /path/to/libExample.so

objdump -T /path/to/libExample.so | c++filt | grep Foo::Bar::_ex
00000000      D  *UND*  00000000              Foo::Bar::_ex
```

For every /path/to/libWhatever.a I collected the library path and output of `objdump -t /path/to/libWhatever.a | c++filt` into ~/adump.txt. Similarly, I collected the path of every .so file and output of `objdump -T /path/to/libWhatever.so | c++filt` into ~/sodump.txt.

When I grep adump.txt for Foo::Bar::_ex, I get only entries like the following:

```
00000000         *UND*  00000000 Foo::Bar::_ex
00000108 g     O .data.rel.local        00000004 Foo::Bar::_ex
```

When I grep sodump.txt for Foo::Bar::_ex, I get only entries like the following:

```
00000000      D  *UND*  00000000              Foo::Bar::_ex
004f9bc4 g    DO .data  000000004  Base       Foo::Bar::_ex
00000000009ff5f8 g    DO .data  0000000000000008  Base        Foo::Bar::_ex
```

I understand from the objdump man page that DF means defining a function, and DO means defining an object, and that if I could find a DF entry for Foo::Bar::_ex in some library, my problem would be solved, just use that library in the link command.

I don't understand what "Object" means in objdump terms - it obviously isn't function code or a runtime object, so what is it?

How does the app run without complaint about a missing function, when none of the libraries provide anything acceptable to the linker?

Comment: maybe a) the function is never called b) the function is dynamically loaded from a place you didnt look (run strace to see what so are being read) c) Inlined?

Comment: _I don't understand what "Object" means in objdump terms - it obviously isn't function code or a runtime object, so what is it?_ In this context, it refers to an _object file_, a file containing _object code_ - the compiled or assembled program code, prior to linking. [This page](https://wiki.osdev.org/Object_Files) explains the concept and it's history. As it says there, the term predates OOP by over a decade.

Comment: @Schol-R-LEA No, objdump shows you whether the symbol is a function or an object.

Comment: I am not sure I quite understand the question. Given `00000000009ff5f8 g    DO .data  0000000000000008  Base        Foo::Bar::_ex`, it seems that `Foo::Bar::_ex` is an object, not a function, and that there seems to be the definition of the symbol. Why are you looking for a function specifically?

Comment: @user17732522 ELF binaries have no concept of 'objects' in the OOP sense. The purpose of `objdump` is to retrieve information from object files and executable files regarding the various sections, e.g., `.text` (code), `.data`, `.rodata` (read-only data, primarily string literals), `.bss` (which defines the uninitialized data region), `.stack` (which defines how large the stack should be), etc. Determining which symbols correspond to code and which to data is only one of its functions.

Comment: @Schol-R-LEA No concept of object in the OOP sense, yes, but what the objdump manual means is most likely "object" in the sense of C and C++ (i.e. "data"), which is not related to "object" in the OOP sense, as opposed to "function" in the sense of C and C++ (i.e. `.text`).

Comment: @user17732522: I am looking for whatever satisfies the linker the function exists to be called at runtime. An object entry clearly doesn't, so I am assuming a function entry is required.

Comment: @Schol-R-LEA: That page seems to suggest an object in an elf file is code. I would expect that if code existed for the function, then the linker would not complain about it not existing. So I still am left wondering what is the difference between an O entry with the function name and an F entry with the function name. The objdump man page merely explains O is for object, with no further explanation.

Comment: @Greg `O` is for an object with static storage duration and `F` for a function. My question is what you base the assumption that the symbol must be a function on. Did you see a call to the function in the disassembled file? If so, could you add it to the question? The symbol `Foo::Bar::_ex` also doesn't have the correct form for a function with C++ linkage, which should have a parameter list in the demangled symbol name and a function with C linkage in a namespace would be a bit unusual (if even allowed?)

Comment: @pm100: a) AFAIK it doesn't matter if it isn't called, it still has to exist so the linker can find it. It could be stripped out if not called with -s. b) Maybe c) Inlined means the function call is replaced by its code, so the dependency would not exist and the linker wouldn't need it.

Comment: @user17732522: that bit about O being static storage is useful info, I was hoping someone could add some such detail :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I found out my real problem today, and it isn't what I thought. I have one shared library that is somehow buggered in a way where it only works if you pass the path to it on the command line instead of using -L and -l.

In other words, just for this one library, `g++ -L /path/to/lib/dir -l libName.so` does not work. The linker says it cannot find any of the functions in it, which clearly exist. It doesn't complain about the file not being found, it just can't find the functions.

If I use `g++ /path/to/libName.so`, now it is happy, and links the app with the specific path given. As long as that path can be loaded at runtime, it works.

So the dorky process I use is to copy the lib to the current dir, give just the name of the library to g++, then remove the copy. The exe is then able to find the library in the usual way at runtime.

Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Well today I was going through the "fun" exercise of trying to pull in all the dependencies (read: lost of swearing, just not loud enough for anyone else to hear), and was getting frustrated with linker errors about can't find a compatible libstdc++ implementation.

So I rolled back the set of OS packages I was installing in my docker container thru a Dockerfile, and .... it worked! Suddenly linking succeeded.

As far as I can tell, I started bringing in some unrelated OS packages that provide libraries whose names are similar to totally unrelated libraries that were sitting in a directory (god only knows where they came from).

Linking to the unrelated OS packages starts asking for other OS stuff, and things quickly go off the rails from there. Once I linked just to the provided libraries of unknown origin, my problem went away :)

Thanks for your answers, lesson learned!